# Python combinations of overlapping pairs on a list

Tags: python, hadoop, combinations

I'm running a Python script as a Hadoop streaming job, but this post is more related to some core Python concepts than knowledge about Hadoop.

Basically I have a set of lines where I want to find overlap

```
$ cat sample.txt
ID1    2143,2154,
ID2    2913,14545
ID3    2143,2390,3350,5239,6250
ID4    2143,2154,2163,3340
ID5    2143,2154,2156,2163,3340,3711
```

I want in the end to find overlapping pairs of records and count them, for example here something like:

```
2143,2154    3
2143,2163    2
2143,3340    2
2154,2163    2
2154,3340    2
2163,3340    2
```

The way I do this is by creating a Hadoop streaming job written in Python where the mapper will basically output all pair combinations on a given line which will be processed further by the reducer.

My question is actually quite simple: how can I generate **efficiently** in Python the combination of all pairs in a given line? Note that in my case a pair (x,y) is the same as a pair (y,x). For example for `ID3` i'd like the following list generated in my mapper:

```
[(2143,2390), (2143,2390), (2143,3350), (2143,5239), (2143,6250), (2390,3350), (2390,5239), (2390,6250), (3350,5239), (3350,6250), (5239,6250)]
```

I can certainly do this with a bunch of for loops but it's quite ugly. I've tried using itertools but couldn't get something out of it properly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
x = [2143, 2390, 3350, 5239, 6250]
itertools.combinations(x, 2)
```

gives:

```
(2143, 2390) (2143, 3350) (2143, 5239) (2143, 6250) (2390, 3350) (2390, 5239) (2390, 6250) (3350, 5239) (3350, 6250) (5239, 6250)
```

Comment: That seems to work fine as well thanks, any thoughts about efficiency compared to @aix 's generator and `ifilter` solutions?

Comment: (+1) I think this is the best solution.

Comment: +1, but you need to sort it before, i.e. `combinations(sorted(x)`

Comment: @thg435: the data in the question is already sorted so there's no benefit in a second sort

Comment: Just as a FYI for those who will read the question later, I ended up using @aix solution with a generator since EMR where I'm running my job only has Python 2.5.2 so no `itertools.combinations`, but I'm keeping this accepted as in another context this is what the best solution would have been.

Answer (score 2):

If `l` is the list in question

```
[(x, y) for x in l for y in l if x < y]
```

Alternatively, you could create a generator:

```
def pairs(l):
  for x in l:
    for y in l:
      if x < y:
        yield x, y
```

This has the advantage of being able to generate pairs "on the fly", without having to keep them all in memory at the same time.

Something similar can be achieved using `itertools.product(l, l)`, but this would generate both `(x, y) and (y, x)`, and will also produce pairs like `(x, x)`. To filter those out, you'd have to do something like:

```
itertools.ifilter(lambda (x,y): x < y, itertools.product(l,l))
```

Comment: Nice I like the generator solution, I tried to complexify this too much ! Could the itertools module have been useful here as well?

Comment: @linker: Sort of. `itertools.product()` comes pretty close. See the updated answer.

Comment: Great, what would be the most efficient solution between the generator one and the `itertools.ifilter` solution?

Comment: Looping on all N**2 to throw half of the pairs away with an `if` seems wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong about the trivial

```
for i, x in enumerate(L):
    for y in L[i+1:]:
        whatever(x, y)
```

?

This will call `whatever` passing each distinct pair of elements from `L` (by distinct I mean with distinct index, they may be equal if `L` contains duplicates).